# Excel does not have enough memory to start error

Tags: microsoft-excel, out-of-memory

Every morning I come into work and fire up excel and get greeted by a lovely "There is not enough memory to run excel." error. There are no other applications running and it is fixed by a reboot.

It's excel 2003 standard fully patched running on Windows XP Service pack 2?

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this problem?

Comment: Memory leak? Have you checked if there actually is free memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved ... The problem is a memory leak in Visual Studio 2008 (or some add-in), it was consuming ~500MB of memory from running unit tests. Closing and re-opening it does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of troubleshooting steps you can take:

1. Make sure your HD is not completely full.  You can get out of memory errors if you don't have enough available HD space.  (Eric Lippert has a [nice blog post on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx), if a bit technical).
2. Get [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  Run it and sort the processes by Working Set and then by Virtual Size to see if any background processes are taking up too much memory.  I know you said no applications are running, but since it happens in the morning and a reboot fixes it, it might be the case that something that is running in the background (service for example) is taking up a large amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Excel 2010 version, which can probably give you faster performance. Also consider using PowerPivot to work with a lot more data than normal pivot table